# Clickhouse Extremely Slow

Tags: olap, clickhouse, object-oriented-database, clickhouse-client

I'm attempting to benchmark clickhouse against postgres for API use.

The dataset is ~40M records

```
SELECT
    name,
    web_url,
    image_url,
    visitor_id,
    web_id 
FROM analytics WHERE event_id = (
    SELECT uuid
    FROM interaction_logs
    WHERE path_id = '12bc4ca0ed14ds3a8ab5d2061c2e551a18a936f14d' ) 
ORDER BY visitor_id ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

However, this query takes approx ~2S to run. This is extremely bad for anything production under any user-load. Is this normal? If not what can i do to improve it?

The server is a AWS c5a.8xlarge instance (32 vCPU/64GB RAM)

I've attempted to set the max_threads and max memory per query, both did not impact performance.

The actual table creation query:

```
CREATE TABLE analytics(
    `uuid` UUID, 
    ...
)
ENGINE=MergeTree() 
ORDER BY uuid;
```

Comment: This is expected. Clickhouse is not OLTP database.

Comment: There are various strategies you can use to improve performance.  Most involve denormalizing your data (with the side effect of avoiding very large joins) and optimizing your primary/order by key for your query patterns.  Your query is currently doing full table scans of two different tables.

Comment: You will need to post the schema as well. You may have the wrong sort keys/primary key, or are not using skip indexes to help with this particular type of query.